# .NET 6 API CancellationToken in development mode

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, controller, .net-6.0

I have a controller (which inherits from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc ControllerBase) method which has CancellationToken like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //logic async processing, I pass cancellationToken to async methods like
    var players = _dbContext.Players;
    players.ToListAsync(cancellationToken); // here I will have "A task was cancelled" error while debugging
    return Ok();
}
```

and in the real scenario it works without any troubles, there is no timeout so the logic is processed. But when I want to debug it and I reach the request time, so the request will be canceled, I will get the exception "A task was canceled". Is it possible to configure controllers in debug/development mode to override cancellationToken with for example CancellationToken.None, or is it possible to disable cancellationtoken in development mode?

The receive message is a webhook which could be called by the external apps.

Moreover, I cannot use OnActionExecuting because it's not a part of ControllerBase.

Comment: Maybe the client closed the connection because the server didn't respond in a timely manner? What do you mean by "...and I reach the request time..."?

Comment: @AlexandraPetrova yes, exactly, but in general, I mean, I want to catch this timeout in debug mode because I want to process debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at this resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

Example:

```
#if DEBUG

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var players = _dbContext.Players;
    players.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    return Ok();
}
#else

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveMessage() {
    var players = _dbContext.Players;
    players.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    return Ok();
}
#endif
```